# Firefox doesn't incorrect adapt ancestor's width for inner content

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have faced with the problem when nested image width does not affect to the parent node. How should I fix it? [Codepen](https://codepen.io/naumovevgeniy/pen/YzOEEeM)

The picture should be in the center on a blue background

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#root {
  position: absolute;
 height: calc(100% - 70px);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: blue;
  max-height: none;
}

#inner {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="inner">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526512340740-9217d0159da9" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This issue represents only in firefox. In Chrome, Opera, Safari(!!!) works correctly.

Comment: The image appears to render in the correct size already, only not in the correct position (firefox dev tools suggest it got placed outside the left side of the viewport or something?) Give #inner `display: flex; justify:content: center`, and it should work fine in FF as well.

Comment: Yee, it in the center now, but on a red background. It should on a blue background. I've updated an example.

Comment: You have not specified a width for #inner and thus it has taken the width of the parent object. you either want to make the Background of Inner transparent or the same as the image.

Comment: I'm interested, can I achieve the same behavior in Firefox as in Chrome?